# how to get the value of data-id in an html when clicked using javascript forloop and return the value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

this is my html

```
       <ul class="conversations">
            {% if t_ques %}
                <li class="grouping">Today</li>
                {% for item in t_ques %}
                    <li class="active">
                        <a id="convers" class="conversation-button text-[#E8F5FC] my-2" href="{% url 'assistant:continuechat' item.pk %}" data-pk="{{item.pk}}">
                            <i class="fa fa-message fa-regular"></i> {{item.title| truncatewords:04 }}
                        </a>
                        <div class="fade"></div>
                        <div class="edit-buttons">
                            <button><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                            <button class="trash" data-id = "{{item.pk}}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if y_ques %}
                <li class="grouping">Yesterday</li>
                {% for item in y_ques %}
                    <li>
                        <a id="convers" class="conversation-button text-[#E8F5FC] my-2" href="{% url 'assistant:continuechat' item.pk %}" data-pk="{{item.pk}}">
                            <i class="fa fa-message fa-regular"></i>  {{item.title| truncatewords:04 }}
                        </a>
                        <div class="fade"></div>
                        <div class="edit-buttons">
                            <button><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                            <button class="trash" data-id = "{{item.pk}}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if s_ques %}
                <li class="grouping">Previous 7 days</li>
                {% for item in s_ques %}
                    <li>
                        <a id="convers" class="conversation-button text-[#E8F5FC] my-2" href="{% url 'assistant:continuechat' item.pk %}" data-pk="{{item.pk}}">
                            <i class="fa fa-message fa-regular"></i>  {{item.title| truncatewords:04 }}
                        </a>
                        <div class="fade"></div>
                        <div class="edit-buttons">
                            <button><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                            <button class="trash" data-id = "{{item.pk}}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if more_s_ques %}
                <li class="grouping">Previous 30 days</li>
                {% for item in more_s_ques %}
                    <li>
                        <a id="convers" class="conversation-button text-[#E8F5FC] my-2" href="{% url 'assistant:continuechat' item.pk %}" data-pk="{{item.pk}}">
                            <i class="fa fa-message fa-regular"></i>  {{item.title| truncatewords:04 }}
                        </a>
                        <div class="fade"></div>
                        <div class="edit-buttons">
                            <button><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                            <button class="trash" data-id = "{{item.pk}}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
   </div>
```

i've been trying to get the value of any data-pk when being clicked on using javascript but can't seem to achieve that. This kept saying currentTarget not defined and when i replaced it with target, it says the same thing. then if i replace it it with document.querySelector("#convers"), it just give the first value, regardless of which is clicked on

this is my javascript

```
    const conversationButtons = document.querySelectorAll("#convers");
    conversationButtons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener("click", getId);
    });

    function getId(e){
        var idValue = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-pk');
        console.log(idValue); //output corresponding target-id

        if(!chat_id){
            url = `/chat-previous/${idValue}/`
        }else{
            url = 'initiate-chat/'
        }

        return url;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: getId(),
        data: {
            message: usermsg,
            chatId: chat_id,
            // itemId: item_id,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
            action: 'post'
        },
        success: function(json){
            const res = json['chats']
            setTimeout(() => {
                hideTyping();
                body.appendChild(mgses(res, "assistant"));
                scrollToBottomOfResults();
            }, 1000);
            console.log(json)
        },
        error: function(rs, e){
            setTimeout(() => {
                hideTyping();
                body.appendChild(setBotResponse("bot"));
                scrollToBottomOfResults();
            }, 600);
            console.log(rs.error);
        },
    });
```

i used other methods like

```
    const getId = () => {
        console.log(document.querySelector(".conversation-button").getAttribute('data-pk'))
         if(!chat_id){
             url = `/chat-previous/${document.querySelector(".conversation-button").getAttribute('data-pk')}/`

      
         }else{
             url = 'initiate-chat/'
    
         }
    
        return url;
    }

    conversationButtons.forEach(button => {
       button.addEventListener("click", getId);
        console.log(button.getAttribute('data-pk'));
    });
```

still couldn't get what i really want. is there a way i can achieve this?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research ).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Please post RENDERED HTML instead of templates since it is not a PHP issue

Comment: I also strongly suggest you delegate from the container instead of looping the eventListeners - IDs need to be unique and delegating will make the IDs unnecessary

Comment: `querySelectorAll("#convers")` - Full stop on the very first line... Multiple elements with the same `id` is invalid HTML.  So any behavior that you're basing on that is already invalid.

Answer (score -1):

You must have unique IDs

To not even need IDs, you can do this

Delegate and use the class of the button

You also need to preventDefault on the links

```
document.querySelector('.conversations').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let tgt = e.target.closest('.conversation-button');
  if (!tgt) return;
  e.preventDefault(); // don't follow the link
  const idValue = tgt.dataset.pk;
  console.log(idValue); //output corresponding target-id
  const url = chat_id ? 'initiate-chat/' : `/chat-previous/${idValue}/`;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    ......
  });
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You are making multiple wrong assumptions, number one is that you cannot have multiple elements with the same id, it will lead to the exact behaviour that u describe "it takes the first occurance id"

second thing is that you probably want to make the ajaxrequest on click, the way you build your code it does´nt do that.

To adress the issues generate the html like following

```
   button.conversation-button
   button.conversation-button
   button.conversation-button
```

then add a eventlistener to all elements with the class `.conversation-button`, and wrap your ajax call into a function, mostly what u already have.

```
const conversationButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".conversation-button");
conversationButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click", doStuff);
});


...
function doStuff(e) {
   $.ajax( ...
     url: getUrl(e)
...
}

function getUrl(e) {
  let idValue = e.target.dataset.pk;
  let url = ...;
  ...
  return url; // 
}
```

just some pseudo code to let u get an idea, good luck :)

Answer (score -1):

In web page you can not use same id multiple times

You can use class for querySelectorAll instead of id="convers"

Add **e.preventDefault()** function to call ajax instead of redirect to hyper link

**change the html code as below:**

```
<div>
    <ul class="conversations">
        {% if t_ques %}
            <li class="grouping">Today</li>
            {% for item in t_ques %}
                <li class="active">
                    <a class="conversation-button text-[#E8F5FC] my-2" href="{% url 'assistant:continuechat' item.pk %}" data-pk="{{item.pk}}">
                        <i class="fa fa-message fa-regular"></i> {{item.title| truncatewords:04 }}
                    </a>
                    <div class="fade"></div>
                    <div class="edit-buttons">
                        <button><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                        <button class="trash" data-id = "{{item.pk}}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if y_ques %}
            <li class="grouping">Yesterday</li>
            {% for item in y_ques %}
                <li>
                    <a class="conversation-button text-[#E8F5FC] my-2" href="{% url 'assistant:continuechat' item.pk %}" data-pk="{{item.pk}}">
                        <i class="fa fa-message fa-regular"></i>  {{item.title| truncatewords:04 }}
                    </a>
                    <div class="fade"></div>
                    <div class="edit-buttons">
                        <button><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                        <button class="trash" data-id = "{{item.pk}}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if s_ques %}
            <li class="grouping">Previous 7 days</li>
            {% for item in s_ques %}
                <li>
                    <a class="conversation-button text-[#E8F5FC] my-2" href="{% url 'assistant:continuechat' item.pk %}" data-pk="{{item.pk}}">
                        <i class="fa fa-message fa-regular"></i>  {{item.title| truncatewords:04 }}
                    </a>
                    <div class="fade"></div>
                    <div class="edit-buttons">
                        <button><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                        <button class="trash" data-id = "{{item.pk}}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if more_s_ques %}
            <li class="grouping">Previous 30 days</li>
            {% for item in more_s_ques %}
                <li>
                    <a class="conversation-button text-[#E8F5FC] my-2" href="{% url 'assistant:continuechat' item.pk %}" data-pk="{{item.pk}}">
                        <i class="fa fa-message fa-regular"></i>  {{item.title| truncatewords:04 }}
                    </a>
                    <div class="fade"></div>
                    <div class="edit-buttons">
                        <button><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                        <button class="trash" data-id = "{{item.pk}}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

**And change your javascrpt code as below**

```
const conversationButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".conversation-button");
console.log(conversationButtons);
conversationButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click", getId);
});
function getId(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var idValue = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-pk');
    console.log(idValue); 
    
    if(!idValue){
        url = `/chat-previous/${idValue}/`
    }else{
        url = 'initiate-chat/'
    }
    console.log(" url ========= ");
    console.log(url);
    return url;
}
```